# Is there any plugin in wordpress without generating short code for adding image gallery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Is there any plugin in word press without generating short code for adding image gallery,already we have plugin for gallery which is generating short codes at each gallery creation, so is there any plugin without generating short codes at the time of gallery creation and adds the gallery into our required word press page

Comment: Please read SO rules, this question doesn't fit requirement here

Comment: try this ,i hope its works    https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-simple-galleries/